# Storing class instances in recoil

Tags: recoiljs

we're trying to store a class instance as an atom state value. When we get the state value we'd like to copy and then mutate the object by calling methods on it. The code looks something like this:

```
  const [config, setConfig] = useRecoilState<ConfigClass>(configAtom);

  const updateConfig = () => {
    const updatedConfig = _.cloneDeep(config);
    updatedConfig.setProperty1('A');
    updatedConfig.setProperty2('B');

    setConfig(updatedConfig);
  }

  ...
```

The problem here is that doing this results in TypeScript errors such as

```
TypeError: attempted to get private field on non-instance
```

It seems the config value received from the `useRecoilState` isn't a normal instance of the class. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store a function/instance in a recoil state, all recoil states should be of type object notation (without functions), bool, number, strings and others, basically any data type serializable or able to convert to JSON.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I haven't been able to find good rules for what is allowed.